# Get x number of rows in a dataframe at equally spaced index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
            time        value1        value2
    1    1000000    1000009842    1009809435
    2    1000032    2348974923    2343242342
    3    1000342    2342345320    2342342234
    ...
    1000 4324342    2131242353    4234234234
```

I want to get 20 random values where the index are spaced uniformly, indexes

```
10, 20, 30, 40, 50... 200
```

or

```
400, 420, 440, 460... 800
```

Where the index starts from can be random, the only thing that needs to be constant is the index between each returned column.

I've used

```
df.sample(1000)
```

to get a sample of 1000 columns but don't see a way of distributing the indexes equally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.iloc[slice_idx]` for this, with `slice_idx` an array that starts at a random start index and has a constant index width.

E.g.:

```
width = 10
idx0 = np.random.randint(0, len(df))
slice_idx = np.arange(idx0 , len(df), width)
df.iloc[slice_idx]
```

returns the rows `idx0 , idx0+10, idx0+20, idx0+30, idx0+40, idx0+50, ...`

A thing to consider is the minimal length of the array. This can be assured by selecting `idx0` below a certain limit. E.g.:

```
width = 20
min_elements = 10  # minimal number of selected elements
assert len(df) > min_elements * width  # assure the parameters validity

# select idx0 between 0 and len(df) - (min_elements - 1) * width - 1
idx0 = np.random.randint(0, len(df) - (min_elements - 1) * width)
slice_idx = np.arange(idx0 , len(df), width)
df.iloc[slice_idx]  # has at least `min_elements` items
```

Comment: why don't you choose `width` randomly?

Comment: Because the question asks for a solution where the only thing that needs to be constant is the index between each returned column. For other use cases, this might be interesting.

Comment: constant is not predefined, right? you choose randomly 2 parameters, starting point and step

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random start **and** step, you need to sample both randomly:

```
N = 20

# get random start up to max-N
start = np.random.randint(len(df)-N)

# get random step between 1 and max multiplier
step = np.random.randint(1, (len(df)-start)//N+1)

# slice
out = df.iloc[np.arange(start, start+step*N, step)]
```

If you want to give priority to choose the step, then the start:

```
N = 20

step = np.random.randint(1, len(df)//N+1)
start = np.random.randint(0, len(df)//step)
df.iloc[np.arange(start, start+step*N, step)]
```

Example slice:

```
Int64Index([328, 333, 338, 343, 348, 353, 358, 363, 368, 373, 378, 383, 388,
            393, 398, 403, 408, 413, 418, 423],
           dtype='int64')
```

Both approaches will give valid slices but won't give the same distributions. Choosing the start first will favor small steps, choosing the step first will favor early starts.

Comment: imo `start = np.random.randint(len(df)-N)` isn't correct, step should be created first

Comment: @Vitalizzare why not? Unless you accept a step of 0, your start cannot be more than `len(df)-N` if you want to ensure having `N` items. For sure you **can** start by choosing the step, but then you have less degrees of freedom for start. It's just a matter of choice ;)

Comment: if `start=len(df) - N` and `step` happens to be >=2, you'll not get N items, no?

Comment: @Vitalizzare no, in this case step cannot be 2, once start is chosen then step can only be chosen among valid values. I'm assuming a second approach if you want to give step the priority, but this will be the same. Once step is chosen you have less degrees of freedom to choose start.

Comment: Oh yes, now I see. I got too attached to my point of view and made a mistake, sorry ;-)

Comment: It make sense to use this as well for more randomized analysis of the data, thank you